# There is a way to sync current time with video time using JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, synchronization, streaming

### Quest

Im trying to do a "streaming" page of a single video.
People login to a page. All this people are from a single country area then all this people have the same current time.
I have a video file that I want to reproduce at (in example) 4 o'clock. If is 4:05 I need the video have 5 minutes of elapsed time (I can explain if I not explain now).

### Try

Using something similar to:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vid.currentTime;
}
```

To get current video time

And Using something like

```js
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
```

To get the current client time

### Question

But how to sync client time and video time?
Greetings